# Define default boot drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, uefi

I had my laptop (HP Envy) with an HDD disk. I've decided to upgrade it with an SSD disk on a free M.2 socket I had available.

I removed the HDD drive and after I have inserted the new SSD disk and I installed a clean Windows 10 OS.

Then I've copied all contents of the old hard drive to the SSD and formatted it. Then I've plugged it back in the right slot, and when I turn on my computer, it gives a error message 'Boot device not found'. It happens because the computer tries to find an OS in the old HDD formatted drive, however I'm able to boot from the SSD after I press F9 key and select the SSD as the bootloader.

Is there any way to select the SSD as the default boot disk?

Comment: You have to "clone" the old drive to the new one before it will boot, simply copying files will not work.

Comment: The old drive was formatted, so there's nothing  there to be cloned.

Comment: Use `BCDedit` to set the default boot option.

Comment: BCDedit helped me to solve the problem. I had no Windows Boot Manager device defined. Thanks.